# How to fix the .Net Framework 3.5 SP1 Error when publish desktop application C#?

Tags: c#, .net, deployment, prerequisites, msi-patch

I'm trying to Deployment C# desktop app with 'Download prerequisite from the same location as my application'. and when I start the publish wizard I get this Error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       To enable 'Download prerequisites from the same location as my application' in the Prerequisites dialog box, you must download file 'DotNetFX35SP1\dotNetFX20\winforms_64.msp' for item '.NET Framework 3.5 SP1' to your local machine. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=616018.    TestForDeployment

So I don't understand how to deal with's this error I download the .Net 3.5 SP1 but I don't know where should I install it. And if that help I use Visual Studio 2017 to develop this app.

Comment: it sounds like you need to install .Net 3.5 SP1 in order to run your application. that is why they call it prerequisites

Comment: VS2017 does not include this bootstrapper.  Removed for a pretty good reason afaik, already quite a while ago, these 3.5 installs depend on the specific Windows version.  So you never want to mess up a machine with the wrong flavor.  Always pick the "download from vendor" option.